# how to get x and y coordinates of user tap/touch relative to window - android titanium mobile?

Tags: popup, positioning, coordinates, tableview, titanium-mobile

Can any one tell how to get x and y coordinates of user tap/touch relative to window - android titanium mobile??

I need to add a popup view close to tableviewrow when the user select a row. How to determine the x,y (top/left) positions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
row.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    alert('left:'+ e.x + ' top:'+ e.y);
});
```

where row is an object of Titanium.UI.TableViewRow. For other objects (like window/view), you can use same eventlistener.

But remember one thing: it gives the co-ordinates with respect to the corresponding row. i.e. you may get same co-ordinates for all the rows.

Therefor, if you want to popup something on that co-ordinate, you should `addEventListener` to the main window.

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437383/how-to-get-the-touch-point-top-and-left-irrespective-of-the-views-windows-in) might help you as the window or object touch events can help you find the exact points the user have touched on screen.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

On click event of any view or object you get x and y coordinate see this link for more reference:

[Titanium.UI.Window](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Window-event-click)