# touch position relative to the screen. windows phone

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-phone-8, position, screen

Hey I am developing an app for Windows Phone 8 using mvvm pattern.

What I want to find is the position relative to the screen. Such that I always know where on the screen the user has pressed, no matter zoom or anything. Just position relative to screen, because then I can calculate the size of the screen relative to the zoom and position.

What I want is the same as this [Android Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11671451/how-to-get-x-and-y-coordinates-of-user-tap-touch-relative-to-window-android-ti).

Which means I cannot use TransformToVisual as this is in need of an UIElement. Have anybody an idea for this issue?

**extra**
To emphasise the question I know how to get a position of the click inside a canvas. My problem is a position can be many places on screen.

Such as position (x,y) can be in the top left and top right corner. But how can I know where the point is relative to the screen i.e. In which corner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can try to use [TouchPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff434208.aspx) from Xna - it works quite well, and I think will do what you want:

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Touch;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;

public MainPage()
{
   InitializeComponent();

   TouchPanel.EnabledGestures = GestureType.Tap;
   this.Tap += MainPage_Tap;
}

private void MainPage_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
   GestureSample gesture = TouchPanel.ReadGesture();
   Vector2 vector = gesture.Position;
   int positionX = (int)vector.X;
   int positionY = (int)vector.Y;
}
```

The top left corner is (0,0) and you get a position relative to it, no matter what orientation your app has.
**EDIT** - few remarks
Note that you can check for TouchInput also in CompositionTarget.Rendering or in Timer - it depends on what you want to achieve.
Note also that when you use XNA you will probably need sometimes to do:

```
FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
```

**EDIT 2** - Pinch example
If you want to use Pinch or other gesture it can look like this:

```
public MainPage()
{
   InitializeComponent();

   TouchPanel.EnabledGestures = GestureType.Pinch;
   this.ManipulationCompleted+=MainPage_ManipulationCompleted;            
}

private void MainPage_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  if (TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable)
  {
     GestureSample gesture = TouchPanel.ReadGesture();
     Vector2 vector = gesture.Position;
     int positionX = (int)vector.X;
     int positionY = (int)vector.Y; 
     // do what you want with your positin
     // there are also some more properties in which you may be interested
     // also TouchPanel has properites like TouchPanel.DisplayWidth and DisplayHeight if you need them
  }
}
```

As for the FrameworkDispatcher.Update() - I think you can call it in OnNavigetedTo().

Comment: Looks interesting, I will try and look that tomorrow. And report back.

Comment: I have tried your code and seems like it does what I want. But it is not the event I need it for. I want it for the pinch event. However I have not been able to do this, can you help me with converting it to use pinch instead? Also FrameworkDispatcher.Update, when should this be called?

Comment: @JTIM I've added in edit 2, what you asked. See also other GestureTypes, maybe you will be interested in them. I've also added Pinch to ManipulationCompleted - note that it can be ManipalationStarted, or delta if you need them.

Comment: okay Thank you I will try this. I tried with manipulationDelta with no success. But I'll try it now thx

Comment: it seems to work, however I am trying to add it in MVVM pattern, using Icommand. But do not know how to do this because of the code you have included in the constructor. Any Idea for this?

Comment: @JTIM It's hard for me to say as I can't see your code and don't know where do you want to use your Pinch. Put it there, where you want to subsctibe to events (MainPage, View etc.).

Answer (score 2):

You need wptoolkit to get Points

Import WPToolkit From Nuget

Cmd: `Install-Package WPtoolkit`

Add this Code inside XAML Grid

```
 <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
        <toolkit:GestureListener
                Tap="GestureListener_Tap"/>
    </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener> <TextBlock x:Name="focusBracket"
                   Text="*"
                   FontSize="48" 
                   Visibility="Collapsed" />
```

in .cs File

```
        private void GestureListener_Tap(object sender, Microsoft.Phone.Controls.GestureEventArgs e)
        {
        try
        {
        Point tapLocation = e.GetPosition(viewfinderCanvas);
        if (tapLocation != null)
        {
            focusBracket.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty,tapLocation.X);
            focusBracket.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, tapLocation.Y);
            double tapX = tapLocation.X;
            double tapY = tapLocation.Y;
            focusBracket.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate()
        {
        this.txtDebug.Text = string.Format("Tapping Coordinates are X={0:N2}, Y={1:N2}", tapX, tapY);
        });
        }
        }
        catch (Exception error){
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate()
        {
        txtDebug.Text = error.Message;

        });

        }

    }
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you I will try and implement it and return :)

Comment: It seems like the point is relative to a canvas? viewfinderCanvas?
Since I can get my position inside the canvas, but I need to know how this position relates to the screen. This is what the code does? I will test it but seems like it is relative to viewfinderCanvas?

Comment: Yes it Need Canvas .. Sorry for not Adding Code Hear

Comment: Okay, so it gives the position relative to this, and not the screen?

Comment: @Siram It seems like you are doing all this in the code behind the XAML, but what if I'm using the MVVM structure is there a smilar way?